# Remove title separator homepage

Tags: php, html, title

I have this php setup for displaying website title:

```
<title>Studio X - <?php echo $titlepage; ?></title>
```

I would like to remove the title separator (-) when website is on the home/landing page  when there is no `titlepage` declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, output `-` only when `$titlepage` not empty:

```
<title>Studio X<?php echo !empty($titlepage) ? (' - ' . $titlepage) : ''; ?></title>
```